# MySQL Appending between 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I need to do a **Appending** on MySql between two tables, my first table1 get all data but
 for the table2 i have only EMAIL :

**table1** (ID;FIRSTNAME;LASTNAME;EMAIL;BIRTH;CP) 100 000 Rows
**table2** (ID;FIRSTNAME;LASTNAME;EMAIL;BIRTH;CP) 1 000 Rows

Exemple

**Table1 :**
1;JOHN;DOE;john.doe@gmail.com;1981-06-06 00:00:00;92220

**Table2 :**
NULL;NULL;NULL;john.doe@gmail.com;NULL;NULL

and
 I want to **UPDATE** on table2 all the  columns to have this match :
1;JOHN;DOE;john.doe@gmail.com;1981-06-06 00:00:00;92220

Answer (score 1):

Use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax to join the tables on `EMAIL` and set the fields appropriately:

```
UPDATE table2 JOIN table1 USING (EMAIL) SET
  table2.ID        = table1.ID,
  table2.FIRSTNAME = table1.FIRSTNAME,
  table2.LASTNAME  = table1.LASTNAME,
  table2.BIRTH     = table1.BIRTH
  table2.CP        = table1.CP
```